# How can one remove only one query-string effectively from an array of values in a given url using URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, query-string

Using this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

If I have a few `color[]` queries in the url and want to remove just `red`, is this the best algorithm to use?

In the following example, I used `.delete()` method and then re-added the ones removed. Is there a more efficient way?

```js
function log(h){document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += h+'<br>';}

let uri = 'http://localhost/?color[]=red&color[]=blue&color[]=green&page=2';
log(uri);
log(''); //space --------

let U = new URL(uri);
let search_params = U.searchParams;

log('current search params:');
for(let [k,v] of search_params.entries()){
log(`${k}: ${v}`);
}
log(''); //space --------


let colors = search_params.getAll('color[]');
log('colors: '+JSON.stringify(colors,null,2));
log(''); //space --------

//remove red by removing all and adding the rest
search_params.delete('color[]');
log('params after delete all colors: ');
for(let [k,v] of search_params.entries()){
log(`${k}: ${v}`);
}

log(''); //space --------

for(let v of colors){
  if(v !== 'red'){
    search_params.append('color[]',v);
  }
}

log('colors after adding all but red: '+JSON.stringify(search_params.getAll('color[]'),null,2));
log(''); //space --------

log('params after removing red: ');
for(let [k,v] of search_params.entries()){
log(`${k}: ${v}`);
}
```

```css
#log { min-height:600px; min-width:600px;}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let search_params_without_red = new URLSearchParams(Array.from(search_params).filter(color => color[1] !== `red`))
```

with some help from here:
https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/335

Comment: gotta use URLSearchParams so that we can reconstruct a URL using the URL object.